# Laravel finding all records from a table where ordering of those records depend on the other table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My database schema is

```
products
--id
--name

orders
--id
--product_id
--quantity
```

From this, I want to find all products, where the order of the products is if the summation of the quantity of a product is less then it will appear first and the highest summation of the quantity of a product appear last. For this my equivalent MySQL code is

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
JOIN (
SELECT product_id,sum(quantity) as s
FROM orders
GROUP BY (product_id)) i on p.id = i.product_id
ORDER BY s ASC
```

How can I do this in laravel easily?

Comment: Define 'easily'.

Comment: Just use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB to build your query. Look at the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements) that page should have everything you need to create that SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have already setup your models with proper relations like products `hasMany()` orders then using eloquent you can get products along with the sum of ordered quantity using [`withSum`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions)

```
 $products = Product::withSum('orders', 'quantity')
                    ->orderBy('orders_sum_quantity')
                    ->get();
```

If you are using older version of laravel which doesn't support `withSum` then you can tweak `withCount` method as

```
 $products = Product::withCount([
                            'orders as quantity' => function ($query) {
                                        $query->select(DB::raw("sum(quantity)"));
                            }
                    ])->orderBy('quantity')
                      ->get();
```